# File not found when starting VM ware player but it does exists?

Tags: vmware

vmWare workstation player v15:
After suspending the VM I wanted to start it again - requesting missing file, this exists but not possible to start anyhow.

Then I cleared the suspended state - Still no luck?

What could be the problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hoa9.png)

Answer (score 0):

from your screen the disk that was not found seems to be only 2KB in size ... I think it is too little like a disk, it is possible that VM was corrupted during suspend/start action?